# Murphy: A probabilistic perspective - Completing the in Variational Inference

Tags: variational-bayes

I don't understand how bishop derives the fact that $q_{\mu}(\mu)$ follows a gaussian distribution by completing the square. On page 774 of the book, a probabilistic perspective, he says the following:

$\text { The optimal form for } q_{\mu}(\mu) \text { is obtained by averaging over } \lambda \text { : }$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\log q_{\mu}(\mu) &=\mathbb{E}_{q_{\lambda}}[\log p(\mathcal{D} \mid \mu, \lambda)+\log p(\mu \mid \lambda)]+\text { const } \\
&=-\frac{\mathbb{E}_{q_{\lambda}}[\lambda]}{2}\left\{\kappa_{0}\left(\mu-\mu_{0}\right)^{2}+\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(x_{i}-\mu\right)^{2}\right\}+\mathrm{const}
\end{aligned}
$$
$\text { By completing the square one can show that } q_{\mu}(\mu)=\mathcal{N}\left(\mu \mid \mu_{N}, \kappa_{N}^{-1}\right), \text {where }$
$$
\mu_{N}=\frac{\kappa_{0} \mu_{0}+N \bar{x}}{\kappa_{0}+N}, \kappa_{N}=\left(\kappa_{0}+N\right) \mathbb{E}_{q_{\lambda}}[\lambda]
$$

Thanks

Comment: We have many posts showing how to complete the square in this context: search our site for [complet* square normal](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=complet*+square+Normal) to find just a few of them.

Comment: yes but in this particular situation I don't know how to complete the square. If I multiply the exponential on both side I don't know how to extract the normalizing constant which will be in the exponent